# In a list of objects X , delete all the objects with property T different than the values present in another list of integers?

Tags: c#, list, iterator

I have a list of integers:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
intList.Add(23);
intList.Add(53);
intList.Add(98);
```

I have a list of Employee objects:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
employeeList.Add(m1);
employeeList.Add(m2);
employeeList.Add(m3);
employeeList.Add(m4);
employeeList.Add(m5);
employeeList.Add(m6);
employeeList.Add(m7);
```

Every object of type Employee has 3 property:

```
int Age;
string Name;
string Gender;
```

Now, I have the list intList with 3 items, the list employeeList with 7 objects.
From the list employeeList I want to completely remove all the Employee that have the property Age DIFFERENT than any of the values present in the list intList.

How's possible to do it in an efficient way?

So for example if `m4.Age=2"` and `m6.Age=98` and all the other Employee have different ages, 
at the end of the elaboration, I want my employeeList to contain only `m4` and `m6` in position 0 and 1.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Why are your integers strings?

Comment: @GolezTrol Probably because `Employee.Age` is also `string`? Which of course is questionable, too.

Comment: `List<int> intList = new List<string>();` can't even be compiled.

Comment: No you don't have a list of integers, because I don't think you can do `List<int> intList = new List<string>();`

Comment: `employeeList.RemoveAll(e => !intList.Contains(e.Age))`

Comment: `List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
intList.add(m1);` That's a typo, right?

Comment: Also, `add` should be `Add`. I've edited this three times already and there are still errors I'm missing. :(

Comment: Now should be Okay, sorry but I had to convert the problem from a bigger class with a lot of dependencies and object names that surely won't make a lot of sense without the whole context...

Comment: Just a thought (doesn't really bear on solving your problem) but, I never use/store age - it changes over time - I use/store birthdate, which is constant and calculate age where I need it.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I'll take it in mind next time I have to deal with birtdays/ages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
employeeList = employeeList.Where(c => intList.Contains(c.Age)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if performance is a concern you can store your integers a bit differently:

```
Dictionary<int, bool> intMap = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
intMap.Add(23, true);
intMap.Add(53, true);
intMap.Add(98, true);
```

Now you can do this:

```
employeeList = employeeList.Where(c => !intMap.ContainsKey(c.Age))).ToList();
```

a dictionary key lookup will outperform a list search.